# Not using second leg of flight with Aer Lingus

Tags: air-travel, hidden-city-ticketing

I have a flight booked from San Francisco > Dublin > Manchester later this year. I have to be in Dublin for business the day after I get to Manchester so rather than flying on I'd prefer to just stay in Dublin.

Is it possible to ditch the second leg of my flight and stay in Dublin with Aer Lingus?

Comment: You should be able to get off but getting your luggage might be a major hassle. See the keyword "hidden city ticketing". Also any subsequent legs (e.g. a return from Manchester/Dublin to SF) would likely be cancelled.

Comment: Is this a return ticket starting from the US?

Comment: @Berwyn yeah it is

Comment: Then you can't do this. Your return flight(s) will be cancelled

Comment: @Berwyn Sorry there might be some confusion, I will have already flown from Manchester to SF a week before. This is my return flight.

Comment: Ok. In that case you're fine apart from the problem with checked bags. No problem if hand luggage only